# Is stackstatus.com related to stackstatus.net?

Tags: support, google, stackstatus

I [googled `stackstatus`](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackstatus) today and the first result shown was https://www.stackstatus.com

Is the domain somehow related to https://www.stackstatus.net? (This was the second result.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not. It seems to be something similar to stackstatus.net, but then for customers of a hosting company called "20i". I never heard of them before, but with a [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stackstatus.com%22) I found [this article on their website](https://www.20i.com/support/web-hosting/server-status):

> #### How do I check 20i server status?
>
> You or your customers can check the status of the 20i platform on the Stack Status page: https://www.stackstatus.com/.

Comment: Also, quick [whois lookup](https://who.is/whois/stackstatus.com) reveals the domain is owned by some Canadian internet services company, unrelated to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard well, there's [not much information for stackstatus.net either](https://who.is/whois/stackstatus.net), but [the postal code does match](https://who.is/whois/stackoverflow.com) ...